# optimizar consulta sql, para que la respuesta sea mas rapida

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqldb

tengo esta consulta en MySQL. Estoy tratando de que el tiempo de respuesta sea mas rápido, pero no logro obtener resultados. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a cómo optimizarla, quitándole los join, o qué más puedo hacer para que la respuesta sea mas rápida?

```
SELECT S.IDSocio, U.IDUsuario, 
CONCAT( S.Nombre, ' ', COALESCE(S.Apellido, '') ) AS NombreSocio, 
U.Nombre AS NombreFuncionario, 
P.IDPregunta,P.TipoCampo, ER.Valor,DATE(ER.FechaTrCr) AS Fecha,ER.FechaTrCr 
FROM Encuesta E, Pregunta P, EncuestaRespuesta ER 
LEFT JOIN Socio S ON ER.IDSocio = S.IDSocio 
LEFT JOIN Usuario U ON  ER.IDSocio = U.IDUsuario 
WHERE  P.IDEncuesta = E.IDEncuesta 
AND ER.IDPregunta = P.IDPregunta 
AND E.IDClub = 8 
AND E.IDEncuesta = 214 
AND P.Publicar = 'S' 
ORDER BY ER.IDEncuestaRespuesta DESC
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE `Socio` (
  `IDSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `IDSocioSistemaExterno` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'Identificador del socio en otro sistema',
  `IdentificadorExterno` char(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `IDClub` int NOT NULL,
  `IDNacionalidad` int NOT NULL,
  `IDPais` int NOT NULL,
  `IDDepartamento` int NOT NULL,
  `IDCiudad` int NOT NULL,
  `IDCategoria` int NOT NULL,
  `IDParentesco` int NOT NULL,
  `IDParentescoZeus` char(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `IDTipoSocioZeus` char(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `IDEstadoZeus` int NOT NULL,
  `IDEstadoSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `IDSocioPresalida` int NOT NULL,
  `IDCursoNivel` int NOT NULL,
  `IDEstadoSalud` int NOT NULL,
  `IDAreaSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `IDPermisoServicio` int NOT NULL,
  `IDPaisDian` int NOT NULL,
  `IDDepartamentoDian` int NOT NULL,
  `IDCiudadDian` int NOT NULL,
  `Accion` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccionPadre` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parentesco` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE `Usuario` (
  `IDUsuario` int NOT NULL,
  `IDPais` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IDDepartamento` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IDCiudad` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IDPerfil` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
  `IDClub` int NOT NULL,
  `IDServicio` int DEFAULT '0',
  `IDServicioElemento` int DEFAULT '0',
  `IDArea` int NOT NULL,
  `IDCursoSede` char(80) NOT NULL,
  `IDAreaSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `TipoUsuario` set('admin','club') DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumeroDocumento` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(80) DEFAULT '',
  `Password` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Autorizado` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  `Nivel` int DEFAULT '1',
  `Permiso` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `PermiteReservar` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `Lenguaje` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Foto` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

  
);

CREATE TABLE `Encuesta` (
  `IDEncuesta` int NOT NULL,
  `IDClub` int NOT NULL,
  `IDModulo` int NOT NULL,
  `IDGrupoSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `DirigidoA` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Descripcion` text NOT NULL,
  `Orden` smallint NOT NULL,
  `SolicitarAbrirApp` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `UnaporSocio` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `FechaInicio` date NOT NULL,
  `FechaFin` date NOT NULL,
  `Imagen` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `RespuestaGuardar` text NOT NULL,
  `ImagenEncuesta` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `DirigidoAGeneral` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `InvitadoSeleccion` text NOT NULL,
  `UsuarioSeleccion` text NOT NULL,
  `SeleccionGrupo` text NOT NULL,
  `Publicar` char(1) NOT NULL,

);
CREATE TABLE `EncuestaRespuesta` (
  `IDEncuestaRespuesta` int NOT NULL,
  `IDEncuesta` int NOT NULL,
  `IDSocio` int NOT NULL,
  `IDPregunta` int NOT NULL,
  `Valor` text NOT NULL,

);
CREATE TABLE `Pregunta` (
  `IDPregunta` int NOT NULL,
  `IDEncuesta` int NOT NULL,
  `TipoCampo` char(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `EtiquetaCampo` text NOT NULL,
  `Obligatorio` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `Valores` text NOT NULL,
  `Orden` smallint NOT NULL,
  `Publicar` char(1) NOT NULL,

)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes creadas tus llaves primarias y foráneas con sus respectivas relaciones?

Comment: si señor ya están creadas en las tablas la consulta funciona bien pero necesito que sea mas rápida al momento de mostrar los datos

Comment: indices? cantidad de datos? explain plan? como podriamos ayudar a algo, de lo cual no sabemos mucho...

Comment: No va a optimizar la consulta, pero deberías de corregir los JOINS para usar la sintaxis de JOIN en vez de unir las tablas con comas.

Comment: con los join hace que tarde mas la consulta y hace que el servidor colapse por la cantidad de datos de la tabla

Comment: Para recibir ayuda de optimización, necesitas mostrar la estructura de tablas, índices, cantidad de datos por tabla y el plan de ejecución.

Comment: son tablas bastante grandes no me deja ni poner la estructura en el comentario, solo necesito que me digan como puedo optimizar mas la consulta

Comment: no podemos decirte como optimizar algo que no vemos!!! no necesitamos las estructuras completas, pero si el explain plan y la parte de las estructuras que estan en el query, y los indices... optimizra un query no es mirarlo y listo... SQL no funciona asi.. si no, tendrias mil paginas que te dirian como optimizarlo.. y fijate.. no tenes ninguna y hay que preguntarlo.... por algo, te pedimos las cosas.. saber si hay 1000 datos o 100 millones tambien es importante...

Comment: tu query hace por lo menos 3 full joins entre 3 tablas.. ya ahi, te diria que hay algo que esta mal.. pero no se que, porque no se ni como se relacionan las tablas!

Comment: Prueba esta herramienta: http://sqlfiddle.com/
Intenta colocar tus tablas para que veamos la estructura y así poder ayudarte

Comment: tampoco me deja colocar la estructura de la tabla debido que las tablas tienen muchos campos

Comment: logre colocar el create de las tablas aunque le quite muchos campos.

Comment: Inclui solo los campos que estan en la query!!! ayudanos a entender tu problema.. donde estan todos los indices?? donde estan la cantidad de registros de cada tabla....

Comment: coloque el resultado de la consulta de unos datos pero en si son 20.000 que da como respuesta, en si el problema es que necesito reducir el tiempo de respuesta porque en la pagina web no me muestra los datos

Comment: Para comenzar, prueba con `ALTER TABLE EncuestaRespuesta ADD INDEX EncPreSoc(IDEncuesta,IDPregunta,IDSocio);` y usa JOINs para `Pregunta`.

Comment: ¿Ninguna tabla tiene índices?